# Passing object of select back to parent in React dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, state, react-props

I'm having a couple of questions with my React dropdown component. Basically, I want to get the selected object from the dropdown back to the Parent component. Right now the dropdown list is working and I seem to be able to get back a {this.state.selectedUser} to the parent from the Dropdown component. The only thing that isn't working is the default value.

From the parent, I want to pass some details from the object selected from Dropdown to a sister component, UserIcon.

First I have my dropdown which has an onChange. I was attempting to add a defaultValue to the Select to fix the issue of no default but no dice so far.

```js
import React from 'react';

class PolicyDropdown extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let initialUsers = this.props.state.users;

    let alphabetizeUsers = initialUsers
      .sort((a, b) => {
        return a.name > b.name;
      })
      .map(obj => {
        return (
          <option key={obj.id} value={obj.name}>
            {obj.name}
          </option>
        );
      });

    return (
      <select
        onChange={e => this.props.onChange(e.target.value)}
      >
        {alphabetizeUsers}
      </select>
    );
  }
}

export default UserDropdown;
```

Then I have a middle component that makes the api call .

```js
import UserDropdown from './UserDropdown';

class UserHeader extends React.Component {
  state = {
    users: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let initialUsers = [];
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/users')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ users: data });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <UserDropdown state={this.state} onChange={this.props.onChangePolicy} />
    );
  }
}

export default UserHeader;
```

And finally the main component where I should be handling the data, and passing the information from the dropdown into a new component, UserIcon.

```js
class Main extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedUser: this.props.user
  };

  onChangeUser = user => {
    this.setState({ selectedUser: user });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <span className="App-title">
            SELECT A POLICY:{' '}
            <UserHeader onChangeUser={this.onChangeUser} />
          </span>
          <br /> <br />
          <UserIcon onChangeUser={this.onChangeUser}  />
          Dropdown value here: {this.state.selectedUser}
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Where the value is displayed as this.state.selectedUser. When I changed the value to just obj, I tried doing this.state.selectedUser.name but the console complained `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`
. I want to pass the id as a prop to UserIcon component for it to use as a variable.

Comment: It's not very clear what is it that you're trying to do... If you want to get back the whole selected user object in your Main component, you need to pass it through a callback when you select it in the dropdown. I don't see that anywhere. In any case, could you explain your question a little better?

Comment: @SrThompson Sure, I think I didn't explain it very well. That is what I want to do, pass the whole selected user object in the Main component when you select it in the dropdown. Then pass details from the object to a sister component.

Comment: @SrThompson I edited the question, hopefully it's more clear? I think you're right, I need to pass it through a callback, I'll try to work on that, but I think that's the main issue where I'm getting confused.

Comment: Definitely, if that's your issue then you need to pass the object back to the Main component somehow, and passing a callback is the simplest way.

Comment: @SrThompson Any chance you have any examples or a code snippet? Maybe I've been staring at it too long but I've been a bit stuck on how to pass stuff around for a while

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the user object back to Main via a callback. This is a simplified version of what that would look like:

```
const UserIcon = props => <div>{props.user.name}</div>;

class UserDropdown extends React.Component {

  render() {
    let initialUsers = this.props.state.users;

    let alphabetizeUsers = initialUsers
      .sort((a, b) => {
        return a.name > b.name;
      })
      .map(obj => {
        return (
          <option key={obj.id} value={obj.id}>
            {obj.name}
          </option>
        );
      });

    return (
      <select
        onChange={e => this.props.onChange(e.target.value)}
      >
        {alphabetizeUsers}
      </select>
    );
  }
}

class UserHeader extends React.Component {
  state = {
    users: [
      {name: "thompson", id: 1},
      {name: "anderson", id: 2}
    ]
  };

  handleChange = selectedId => {
    const selectedUser = this.state.users.find( el => el.id === selectedId);
    this.props.onChange(selectedUser);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <UserDropdown state={this.state} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedUser: {
      name: "",
      id: ""
    }
  };

  onChangeUser = user => {
    this.setState({ selectedUser: user });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <span className="App-title">
            SELECT A POLICY:{' '}
            <UserHeader onChange={this.onChangeUser} />
          </span>
          <br /> <br />
          <UserIcon user={this.state.selectedUser} />
          Dropdown value here: {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean by passing to the UserIcon component, which is great. But I'm still stuck because it is only returning the obj.name in the Main component, not the whole object with the name and the id. I can't figure out why

Comment: I did a quick test on codesandbox and it was passing the whole object. Are you keeping your user objects on the users array in a similar shape as  the one shown in this answer?

Comment: @SrThomas I just got it, I was experimenting with value={obj.id} and took it out at one point so the main component was only getting the name. However, the sister/child component isn't getting the value, or at least it's not rerendering when it gets it

Comment: Verify that you're passing the selected user to the UserIcon from the Main component state. It should re-render each time Main has its state updated.

Comment: I think I got it with componentWillReceiveProps. Now it is updating. Just need to add componentDidMount as well, feel like I'm duplicating code though

Comment: That's probably due to the way you have set up your state. Consider pulling common state up to avoid re-checking every time. Although I don't know why you needed componentWIllReceiveProps in this case, but that's probably due to your UserIcon implementation